# SMART Extended Self-test keeps aborting "manually"

Tags: smart, toshiba-hard-drive

So I have this older 1TB Toshiba hard drive (P/N MK1059GSM), and it won't finish a Smart Extended Self-Test... The drive seems to work fine in operation, and a short self-test completes normally, but after about 15 minutes of performing an extended self-test GSmartControl says the test aborted manually and the raw output says "Aborted by host". The drive is docked in a Thermaltake Black Widow USB/SATA dual disk dock connected via USB.

What would cause this to exit? It isn't failing the test, just aborting it as if someone pressed cancel... Is this something I should be concerned with?

Output of smartctl -a: http://pastebin.com/QeZ0XEvQ

Comment: If failing a self-test isn't a good sign.  What exactly is your question?  It failing would be caused by the drive being in a pre-fail state.

Comment: I would take it out of the enclosure and hook it up direct to a SATA bus and see if the problem persists.

Comment: That is the thing, it isn't "failing"... I have seen drives fail the self-test, that is a very different result, it is stopping the test as if someone pressed CANCEL or ABORT, but that didn't occur. I will connect it directly to a SATA  connection on the motherboard and try again, good idea.

Comment: It appears the USB docking station was the culprit, the test is now 30% complete connected to the SATA port of the motherboard directly, the best it could ever get to plugged into the dock was 10%.

Comment: The Extended Self-test completed successfully connected directly to the SATA bus... must have been something to do with the USB dock.